# Swift package manager keep in loading state forever

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Can not add swift package as it gets stuck on loading state forever as shown in the screenshot.

Xcode version: Version 12.2 (12B45b)

I did try adding package into newly created "Hello World" project and situation the same.

How I could fix it?

[image]

Comment: Something of a long shot, but I seem to recall something like this when I hadn't tagged any commits with an appropriate version tag...

Comment: Try just entering the URL if you've pushed it to GitHub already

Comment: @aheze I did enter URL and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem gets fixed:

- Paste whole URL into the search field
- Hit enter